# vb.net | Can't retrieve data using license plate numbers but can retrieve using LastName and id_num

Tags: sql, vb.net, get

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database table but it's only accepting id_num and LastName.
This is my code below. This code is working if I'm using id_num=@parm1 but if I change it to PlateNumber it says no data when clearly there's a column named PlateNumber on my database (phpmyadmin). Am I missing something? Is it because the plates have letters and numbers? Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

```
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT id_num, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Contact, PlateNumber, OwnerType FROM ownerinformation where id_num=@parm1", con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", txtPlate.Text)

    Dim myreader As MySqlDataReader
    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If (myreader.Read()) Then
        idNUM.Text = myreader("id_num").ToString
        txtLastName.Text = myreader("LastName").ToString
        txtFirstName.Text = myreader("FirstName").ToString
        txtMiddleName.Text = myreader("MiddleName").ToString
        txtContact.Text = myreader("Contact").ToString
        txtPlate.Text = myreader("PlateNumber").ToString
        SOP.Text = myreader("OwnerType").ToString
    Else
        MsgBox("No data")
    End If

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to change the operatore from `=` to `LIKE` in the WHERE clause. Just to be certain that you don't have some lowercase letter in input while the database has the uppercase version or viceversa

Comment: @Steve still getting no data. But thank you for answering.

Comment: What happens if you try to execute the same query (after replacing the parameter with value present in your textbox) using the MySqlWorkbench or other admin tools for MySql?

Comment: @Steve I tried hard coding the parameter i.e. where PlateNumber='AAZ5211' and it's still not working. No data is being retrieved.

Comment: You need to try with a MySql management tool like MySqlWorkbench and check if you really have a record where the field PlateNumber contains the value passed to the query. If the data exists then check the connectionstring if you are working with the correct database

Comment: @Steve I made it work. The problem was I entered the data on the wrong textbox/parameter. Thank you for your time. :D

Comment: I suggest you to delete this question as soon as possible then to avoid closure or downvotes.